# How do I run a ps1 script file passed by parameter from inside a powershell function?

Tags: powershell

I need to write a function in PowerShell that receives a bunch of parameters, one of them being a ps1 file. I need to execute this file as part of my function code, but I don't know how to do that.

This is probably a very silly detail, but I failed horribly in trying to search for this.

This is my function at the moment. I tried using `Invoke-Command` there but it's not working:

```
Function Start-Dsc {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $configurationFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $configurationName,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $configurationData,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $computerName
    )

    Begin {}
    Process 
    {
        Invoke-Command -Command "$configurationFile -ConfigurationData $configurationData";
        Start-DscConfiguration -Path ".\$configurationName" -ComputerName $computerName -Verbose -Wait
    }
    End{}
}
```

UPDATE:

With Bacon Bits' help, I managed to make it work. The final script is a bit different than what I initially posted though. This is the final process block:

```
Process 
{
    Invoke-Command -FilePath $configurationFile -ComputerName 'localhost';
    Invoke-Expression -Command "$configurationName -ConfigurationData $configurationData";
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path ".\$configurationName" -ComputerName $computerName -Verbose -Wait
}
```

Comment: Will you need access to things in that file within the current script? For example, will you need functions from that other script to be available in the current script? Will the script be run in the current session or will it need to be run on another computer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I needed the results of the script execution, and all commands need to be run on the local machine. I've updated the question with the latest version of my block of code, which is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are a separate option in `Invoke-Command`.  Try:

```
Invoke-Command -Command "$configurationFile" -ArgumentList "-ConfigurationData $configurationData";
```

You may also need to change `-Command` to `-FilePath`.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. I managed to make it work, and now I finally understand how `Invoke-Command` and `Invoke-Expression` works. I had to add the `computerName` parameter to the call though, as you can see from my update.